# Is this a poset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Is $(S, R)$ a poset where $S$ is the set of all people in the world and $(a, b) \in R$, where $a$ and $b$ are people if $a$ is no shorter than $b$?

My attempt:

$a$ is no shorter than $a$. This is not reflexive because $a$ can be taller than $a$. Contradiction

True?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you shorter than yourself? I kind of doubt it. Thus, $\langle\text{Don Larynx},\text{Don Larynx}\rangle\in R$. The same goes for anyone else, so $R$ is reflexive.

You may be having trouble with *no taller than*: $a$ is no taller than $b$ if the height of $a$ is $\le$ the height of $b$. From this it’s also not hard to check that $R$ is transitive.

The crucial property is antisymmetry. What happens if there are two different people whose heights are equal?

Comment: Such an old question, but I'm struggling with this so bad: "From this it’s also not hard to check that  is transitive." I can't understand this. How can something can be transitive when we have only (a, b). There is no c, certainly not one with any relationship to (a,b). I hate transitive. It makes no sense when we only have 2 items.

Comment: @MoteZart: $R$ is a relation on $S$, the set of all people in the world, so $S$ has far more than just two members. However, the size of the set $S$ actually has no bearing on whether $R$ is transitive. Transitivity says that whenever $a,b,c\in S$ are such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$ and $\langle b,c\rangle\in R$, then $\langle a,c\rangle\in R$. The only way this can fail is for there to be $a,b,c\in S$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$, $\langle b,c\rangle\in R$, and $\langle a,c\rangle\notin R$. Note that the elements $a,b$, and $c$ don’t have to be distinct. For instance, the ...

Comment: ... relation $\ne$ on $\{0,1\}$ fails to be transitive because $0\ne 1$ and $1\ne 0$, but it’s not true that $0\ne 0$; here I’m taking $a=0,b=1$, and $c=0$. For the $R$ of the question, if $a,b$, and $c$ are any people, possibly but not necessarily distinct, $a$ is at least as tall as $b$, and $b$ is at least as tall as $c$, then it must necessarily be true that $a$ is at least as tall as $c$. (Note that *is not shorter than* means exactly the same thing as *is at least as tall as*.) If $h(x)$ is the height of $x$ for any $x\in S$, then $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$ if and only if ...

Comment: ... $h(a)\ge h(b)$, and $\langle b,c\rangle\in R$ if and only if $h(b)\ge h(c)$; and if $h(a)\ge h(b)$ and $h(b)\ge h(c)$, then certainly $h(a)\ge h(c)$.

Answer (score 2):

False. How can $a$ be taller than himself? Every person is exactly of their own height, and not an atom taller. Therefore every person is not shorter than themselves. So the relation is reflexive.

It is also transitive, because if I am not shorter than you, and you are not shorter than my dad, then I am certainly not shorter than my dad.

However, this fails to be anti-symmetric. What happens if we are both of the same height?

Comment: You will not melt together or something like that, but is it beyond any doubt that two distinct persons exists having exactly the same length? If this does not occur then the relation is vacuously anti-symmetric.

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't the antisymmetric relation property defined as this: $\forall a,b\in X $ $R_0(a,b)\land R_0(b,a) \rightarrow a = b$? So if $(a,b)\in R$ when $a\ge b$ how does this relation not satisfy the antisymmetry.

Comment: @drhab, physically you are probably correct that in all probability height is something rather unique if we use an infinitely accurate measurement. However these examples when given (and I hate it when they are) are usually treating our intuition as for height and formalize in centimeters, or millimeters, or fraction of inches if you prefer. I doubt that you would say that me and someone $1\rm\ mm$ taller than me are not of the same height. I doubt you could even prove we are but one millimeter apart.

Comment: @lnwvr: Yes. Suppose both of us are of the same height, neither is shorter than the other. Then $(\textrm{Asaf,lnwvr}),(\textrm{lnwvr,Asaf})\in R$. Are we the same person?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah yes, the height is a property of the elements in the set and not a element itself. Thx

Comment: @AsafKaragila This is from Rosen's book. I hate it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila if you are both of same height, doesn't that mean two people are both not shorter than each other, a contradiction? (True or False?)

Comment: @DonLarynx: Contradiction to what? Also why are you reading it, then?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Homework. Is my statement true or false?

Comment: @DonLarynx: It has no meaning. Write it properly. What are you contradicting?

Comment: $a$ is no shorter than $b$ and $b$ is no shorter than $a$ implies $a$ is no shorter than $a$ implying reflexivity @AsafKaragila. Please bear with me here, I've always had difficulty with posets :\

Comment: @DonLarynx: I think you should just read the definitions again. Carefully. Partial ordered sets are not very difficult. It seems that you have decided that you will not understand this concept, no matter what. Your last comment seems like you're trying to write "voodoo words" in hopes of writing a correct statement. The result, I'm afraid, makes little to no sense to my eyes. Relax, read the definitions slowly and carefully again, and ponder them for a few minutes. It will work out just fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11478/discussion-between-don-larynx-and-asaf-karagila)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some modelling.

Let $P$ be a set, $l:P\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
a function and $R\subset P\times P$ the relation defined by $pRq\iff l\left(p\right)\geq l\left(q\right)$

Clearly the relation is reflexive and transitive, so it is a preorder.
The relation is anti-symmetric if and only if $f$ is injective. This
shows that $R$ is a partial order if and only if $f$ is injective.

To apply it here identify $P$ with the 'set of all people in the
world' and let $l$ send each person $p\in P$ to its length $l\left(p\right)$.